# R ; How can I build 'for in' loops over datatable?

Tags: r

How can I play loop over datatables?

I have 6 datatable named 'tax2015' 'tax2016' 'tax2017'...'tax2020'.

They have the same header [month, tax, average].

And I'm trying to change the third name of each header, 'average' to 'sum'.

Let's imagine there's 6 datatables named like above, each of them 12 by 3.

```
for (x in tax2015) {
   names(x)[3] <- paste("sum")
}
```

I made code like this and it doesn't work. Don't know why..

```
F <- function(a){
   if(1>0){
      for (x in a)
      names(x)[3] <- paste("sum")
   }
   return(x)
}

F(tax2015)
```

Tried this too, but doesn't work.

Add to this, how can I do this work for 6 serial data.tables 'tax2015' 'tax2016' 'tax2017'...'tax2020' at one time?

like..

```
for(x in tax2015:tax2020) {
   names(x)[3] <- paste("sum")
}
```

This doesn't work, is there some ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in list either manually or using `mget` with specific pattern

```
list_df <- mget(ls(pattern = "tax\\d+"))
#list_df <- list(tax2015, tax2016, tax2017, ...)
```

Then use `lapply` to change name at specific position

```
list_df <- lapply(list_df, function(x) {names(x)[3] <- "sum";x})
```

You can keep the dataframe in list or make them in separate dataframe

```
list2env(list_df, .GlobalEnv)
```

Consider this example,

```
tax2015 <- data.frame(month = 1:5, tax = 6:10, average = 11:15)
tax2016 <- data.frame(month = 1:5, tax = 6:10, average = 11:15)
tax2017 <- data.frame(month = 1:5, tax = 6:10, average = 11:15)
list_df <- mget(ls(pattern = "tax\\d+"))

list_df <- lapply(list_df, function(x) {names(x)[3] <- "sum";x})

list_df
#$tax2015
#  month tax sum
#1     1   6  11
#2     2   7  12
#3     3   8  13
#4     4   9  14
#5     5  10  15

#$tax2016
#  month tax sum
#1     1   6  11
#2     2   7  12
#3     3   8  13
#4     4   9  14
#5     5  10  15

#$tax2017
#  month tax sum
#1     1   6  11
#2     2   7  12
#3     3   8  13
#4     4   9  14
#5     5  10  15
```

Answer (score 1):

As the columns are the same in each case, I'd start with either a list of data frames, or combine them in one, rather than keeping them separate.

This is easy using `bind_rows()` from `dplyr`, which also supplies the useful `rename()` function.

```
library(dplyr)

new_df <- list(tax2015 = tax2015,
               tax2016 = tax2016,
               tax2017 = tax2017,
               tax2018 = tax2018,
               tax2019 = tax2019,
               tax2020 = tax2020) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "id") %>%
  rename(sum = average)
```